# ipywidget interactive hiding visibility

Tags: python, text, widget, visibility, dropdown

I would like to make an interactive module with ipywidgets.
So far so good but I'm stuck.
I want to hide the visibility of a certain ipywidget object dependent on a certain situation, and I want my printed text to show up above the widget and stay there.

```
dropdown=widgets.Dropdown(
    options={'Coffee machine': 1, 'Washing machine': 2, 'Water Heater': 3, 'Heating System': 4, 'Dryer': 5, 'Oven': 6, 'Microwave': 7, 'Other':8},
    value=1,
    description='Apparaat:',
    )
text_new=widgets.Text()
def text_field(value):
    if(value==8):
        display(text_new)
        text_new.on_submit(handle_submit)
    else:
        text_new.visible(False) #Doesn't work but I want something like this
print("Today you had an increase in electricity consumption, would you like to name this device?") #This just be above the dropdown menu and be stuck
i=widgets.interactive(text_field, value=dropdown)
display(i)
```

What this does now:
When "Other" is checked in the dropdown menu, a text box appears where the user can type something.
However, when checking another machine, the text box stays there.
I just need a "hide" function but I can't seem to find one that works.

Also, after checking another option on the dropdown, the print dissapears, not coming back.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Had same problem so i found in

```
boton.layout.visibility = 'hidden'
```

or

```
check.layout.display = 'none'
```

they made  some changes... i got if from here
[Cannot create a widget whose initial state is visible=False](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/674)

Comment: Thank you @pir0, `boton.layout.visibility = 'hidden'` worked for me!  Use `boton.layout.visibility = 'visible'` to make it visible again.

Comment: @RonKalian, there is a difference between the two answers: visibility='hidden' is keeping the bounding box of the field, whereas display='none' completely collapses the field, shifting upward the rest of the form. Btw the opposite is simply the js wording:  display='block'

Answer (score 12):

Given a widget:

```
import ipywidgets
button = ipywidgets.Button()
```

There are two direct ways to hide the the widget, with a notable difference.

Hide and unhide the widget *without affecting overall page layout*:

```
# Turn the widget "invisible" without affecting layout
button.layout.visibility = "hidden"

# Make the widget visible again, layout unaffected
button.layout.visibility = "visible"
```

Hide and unhide the widget *and collapse the space that the widget took up*:

```
# Hide widget and collapse empty space
button.layout.display = "none"

# Re-add the widget, adjusting page layout as necessary.
button.layout.display = "block"
```

When to use each one? As a rule of thumb, use `layout.visibility` so the page layout is not constantly jumping around as visibility is toggled. However, for very large widgets, consider using `layout.display` to avoid huge blank spaces.

---

For more general CSS information that applies here, see [What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the accepted answer, if you want to dynamically change the visibility of a control, you can declare the layout variable and reuse.

```
layout_hidden  = widgets.Layout(visibility = 'hidden')
layout_visible = widgets.Layout(visibility = 'visible')
```

Like attach to an event:

```
def visible_txt(b):
    text_box.layout = layout_visible

def hidden_txt(b):
    text_box.layout = layout_hidden

btn_visible.on_click(visible_txt)
btn_hidden.on_click(hidden_txt)
```

Comment: Interesting... What would be the advantage of assigning the full layout object vs changing solely toggling the `visibility` directly?